# react AG-grid: How to get currency symbol from a cell in ag-grid along with the value

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

working on react AG-grid feature range selection and i am trying to get the sum value of selected cells. i could get the sum of selected cells where as i am not able to get the currency symbol from the same cell. is there any feature AG-grid provides to get the currency symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For currency symbols i think you are looking for [value-formatters](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/value-formatters/)

For a summary of the selection you might want to look into [status-bar](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/status-bar/)
But it's not clear in your question if you are using enterprise or not. Status-bar is an enterprise feature.